# How do I get data for current user only with flutter and firestore

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Am trying to get data for a specific user only using flutter and firestore latest version.
Since firebase has been updated the latest version does't work with the methods I've seen online.

Here's my stream builder

```
final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
//Streams are used to listen to realtime streams of data

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return Row(
              children: [
                Text(data['first name']),
                Text(data['last name']),
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I want to do queries with the 'uid', This gets all the current users data.

I tried this as the stream query but doesn't work

`final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _myUserStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(currentUser!.uid).snapshots(); your text`

I also tried this

`final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('email', currentUser.email).snapshots();`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say Users is a model you made.
in my case its this.

```
  Users.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
uid = map['uid'];
userName = map['userName'];
userNickname = map['userNickname'];
userBirthday = map['userBirthday'];
userEmail = map['userEmail'];
userPassword = map['userPassword'];
userGender = map['userGender'];
userImage = map['userImage'];
userData = (map['userData'] as Map<String, dynamic>?)?.map((key, value) =>
    MapEntry(key, value is List ? List<String>.from(value) : <String>[]));
```

}

You can get the User data using Future this way

```
  Users user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .snapshots()
      .map((event) {
    return event.docs.map((e) {
    
      return Users.fromMap(e.data());
    }).singleWhere(
      (element) => element.userEmail == email,
    );
  }).first;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSBQK.png)
For Streams this way

```
   var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .snapshots()
      .first;
  Users user = snapshot.docs
      .map((e) => Users.fromMap(e.data()))
      .singleWhere((element) => element.userEmail == email);
```

Comment: For those wonder here's my solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

For those wonder what I did.

First I get the user id of the current user.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid
```

The when am creating a profile I pass that id to the user data.

```
UserProfile userProfile = UserProfile(
    firstName: 'First Name',
    lastName: 'Last Name',
    uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

databaseService.addUser(userProfile);
```

The `databaseService` is a custom class with the database functions. Here's the `databaseService` `class addUser(userProfile)` function. `UserProfile` is the model that takes the variables.

```
addUser(UserProfile userProfile) async {
    await _db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .set(userProfile.toMap());
}
```

Here's the user profile class also.

```
class UserProfile {
    final String? id;
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;
    final String uid;

    UserProfile({
        this.id,
        required this.firstName,
        required this.lastName,
        required this.uid,
    });
```

So when am query the data base for a specific user.

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .snapshots();
```

The data I get from the stream has to be used in a streambuilder to access that data. so `_usersStream` is like the query and the streambuilder displays data from that query.

```
// StreamBuilder takes a stream
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _usersStream // This is the query for the stream builder
```

Now to extract that data, check if the data is received successfully. The data received is passed to a `Map`. I can then convert that Map to an `Object`. `Object` would be like a class which in my case is `UserProfile`.

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data =
        snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    // Pass data from map to class
    userData = UserProfile(
        firstName: data['first name'],
        lastName: data['last name'],
        uid: data['uid']);

    // Display data from user data
    return Text("Full Name: ${userData.firstName}");
}
```

I can then use the `userData` to do what I want, display information etc. Pass to other screens all of that.